Is every homogeneous line bundle pulled back from the quotient stack?
Let $G= \mathbb{G}_m^k$ act on a variety $X$.
Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a line bundle on $X$ and assume that for each $g \in G$ the pullback $g^\star \mathcal{L}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}$.
Does it necessarily follow that $\mathcal{L}$ can be pulled back from a line bundle on the quotient stack $[X/\mathbb{G}_m^k]$?
I am particularly interested in the case that $X$ is obtained from several toric varieties by identifying boundary divisors.

No, even if $G$ acts freely. You need more, namely a $G$-linearization on your line bundle. I suggest the first chapter of Mumford's GIT, where this is clearly explained.

It is also discussed in Dolgachev’s book on invariant theory.

thanks both for the references!
